# Reading in JSON with multiple layers

Tags: r, arrays, json, list, dataframe

having troubles with importing a JSON File in R. The JSON has multiple levels, to give you an example:

```
{"events":[],"id":"xxx"}
{"events":[{"__ets":123456789,"session_duration":0,"page":{"page_description":"{{page_description}}","page_title":"page_title","page_category":"page_category","page_type":"corporate","page_language":"en"},"xxx":{},"country":{"country":"uk"},"client":{"business_type":"{{business_type}}"},"interactions":{"session_id":"{{session_id}}"},"conversion_funnel":{},"name":"page_view","ts":123456789,"channel_id":"1234","url":"www.anonymity.com","id":"0"},{"__ets":123456789,"session_duration":0,"page":{"page_description":"{{page_description}}","page_title":"page_title","page_category":"brochure","page_type":"corporate","page_language":"en"},"xxx":{},"country":{"country":"uk"},"client":{"business_type":"{{business_type}}"},"interactions":{"session_id":"{{session_id}}"},"conversion_funnel":{},"name":"xxx","ts":123456789,"channel_id":"1234","url":"www.anonymity.com","id":"1"}],"id":"xxx"}
{"events":[],"id":"xxx"}
{"events":[],"id":"xxx"}
```

JSON example anonymized, but as you can see it's website data. This JSON is "dynamic" if you'd like to call it that way. Meaning, that in the section `events` there can be multiple name-value pairings, but there can be none as well. `id` is always not null.
I tried importing this JSON file with the following code, to give you a reproducible sample:

```
df <- fromJSON(paste0("[", paste0(readLines(json_file), collapse = ","), "]"))
```

This reads the file, but in a strange format: as an observation of 2 variables. When I look at the list in R it looks like this:

[image: example from RStudio]

When trying to click on the *expand* button, it shows me the following error code:

```
Error in View : Attribute 'names' [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

So my question is:

> How can I import the JSON to make it usable in either dataframe or array form?

or

> How can I edit this list to convert it into a dataframe or array?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

@Ronak Shah

```
library(jsonlite)

json_file <- "input/json_file.json"

df <-  fromJSON(paste0("[", paste0(readLines(json_file), collapse = ","), "]"))
```

That's all that's needed to reproduce the error with the given JSON sample.

Comment: This would be difficult to help without an example. Can you try to narrow down the error to smaller subset of data and provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)?

Comment: Hello @RonakShah! The minimal data set is the JSON as seen above in the first code section, due to data protection issues I unfortunately can't provide more.

To give a reproducible example:

Comment: @RonakShah

`library(jsonlite)

json_file <- "input/json_file.json"

df <-  fromJSON(paste0("[", paste0(readLines(json_file), collapse = ","), "]"))`
That's all that's needed to reproduce the error with the given JSON sample.